# AppAuth Implicit Grant

Tags: android, appauth

I am trying to get AccessToken from a OAuth2 based server using Implicit grant using [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) .

after this below code redirected to browser for sign in

```
AuthorizationService service = new AuthorizationService(this,
                new AppAuthConfiguration.Builder().setBrowserMatcher(blacklist).build());

    service.performAuthorizationRequest(request,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, request.hashCode(),new Intent(this,ReceiverActivity.class),0));
    service.dispose();
```

When I get back from browser to app in ReceiverActivity as used in above code, then  at:

```
public viod onStart(){
     AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(getIntent()); //null
            AuthorizationException ex = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(getIntent());// exception below
}
{"type":0,"code":9,"errorDescription":"Response state param did not match request state"}
```

Other:

```
AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
                authorizationServiceConfiguration,
                "clientid",
                "token",
                Uri.parse(CONSTANTS.REDIRECT_URL)
        ).setScope("crm_read")
                .setAdditionalParameters(autoApprove)
                .build();
```

Manifest

```
 <activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="${appAuthRedirectScheme}"
                    android:host="com.crm.crm"
                    android:path="/oauth2callback"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So, why i am getting this error {"type":0,"code":9,"errorDescription":"Response state param did not match request state"}
di I need to set something in the link?

Answer (score 2):

Lead maintainer of AppAuth here - we don't support the implicit flow in the library, as it is not suitable for native apps: it has poor security properties, and would require the user to re-authenticate via the web flow frequently (typically every 7-30 days). A code based flow, where a refresh token can be acquired, is recommended that this would only require the app to authenticate once via the web flow, after which it can transparently acquire new access tokens using the refresh token.

Comment: What about the reverse; can Auth/PCKE be used in the browser context? I'm working with Ionic and planning on PCKE, but I'd like plan ahead for using the app in a browser & and as PWA. And I'd like to do most of my testing in the browser anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can use the code flow + PKCE in a browser. AppAuth-JS implements this: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS

Comment: Hi @iainmcgin is this still the case ? AppAuth does not support implicit flow for native apps ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the IdentityServer4 Documentation, Implicit Grant Type is optimized for browser-based applications. Thus not recommended for Mobile Apps.
For Mobile apps, you should consider Hybrid Flow (code id_token).